# Is there a way to send Task status from microservice on ASP.NET Core to client UI application on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, http, microservices

There is an async method in WPF viewmodel

`var asyncTask = await Service.Execute();`

Execute method is a method of a microservice, which is executed asynchronyously.

Is there any way to send the task status of execute method from microservice to WPF viewmodel ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options, but it all depends a bit on your setup.

The idea is to have a callback to your application, one way or the other. This can be a direct response to the application, the application listening to a shared notification system or by polling.

- Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
- WebSockets / notification system
- Polling
- Message queuing like MSMQ, RabbitMQ, SQS, Azure Service Bus

These methods all have pro's and cons. Depending on the requirements you need to pick a suited one.

Let me elaborate.

#### Remote Procedure Call (RPC)

In this setup the micro service (MS) needs to to communicate back to the UI application. This usually is a bad idea, because you need to make the MS aware of the Client application - and also, you'll need connectivity inbound to the client application.

The Client applicationto host RPC endpoints to make this work.

Normally this is not really an option.

#### WebSockets / notification system

Basically this is a similar method as above. However WebSockets or a notification system like Azure or AWS SNS is likely to overcome the burden of the incoming connection.

I'll add some documentation for some libraries.

#### Polling

This is by far the easiest to implement Client side, but harder in MS side.

Since it's a long running task, after initiation on could send back the ID of the job, (in a [HTTP ACCEPTED](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202) way (assuming you use HTTP to interact with the MS), and periodically request the status of the given job at the MS.

#### Message queuing like MSMQ, RabbitMQ, SQS, Azure Service Bus

This is unlikely, but I want to name it for completeness.

Often MS inter process communication is done over a Message Queuing (MQ) mechanism. You could hook up the application onto this MQ system and let it listen to an event/message broadcasted by the MS.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Among all polling is the most pragmatic. Let me give some details. On the MS controller there is a method which returns the current job ( async task ). My question is, is how to run this job method periodically in view model and the job exactly ( async task ), so that we could receive status.IsCompleted property from method which returns current job ?

var asyncTask = await Service.Execute();

Comment: Whether or not you start this task from a viewmodel is up to you , but keep in mind you might loose the state when navigating to another window or shutting down the application. I would google that, but - you can do it with a timer... or even starting the task from the task recursively.

Comment: @P3ar1baron: this should do the trick:
https://nitinmanju.medium.com/a-simple-scheduled-task-using-c-and-net-c9d3230769ea

Comment: thanks for the link, if I understood correctly that there job status retrieve method should be put instead of action delegate in recurring task from the manual, you've sent. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. But, since Execute method is awaited, till the task is finished, where to put the recurring task with job status method ?

Comment: @P3ar1baron: this depends. To verify this: if `var asyncTask = await Service.Execute();`, is then the task finished as well? If so, my answer does not make any sense because the handling in the MS is synchronous then.